# sqlldr return codes - ex_warn

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, return-code

I want to know if my file is loaded complete in the database.

if you check the return codes [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch04.htm#1005020) you can see that 1 and 3 is a fail.

```
EX_SUCC 0
EX_FAIL 1
EX_WARN 2
EX_FTL  3
```

EX_WARN(return code 2) includes this cases:

```
All or some rows rejected EX_WARN

All or some rows discarded EX_WARN

Discontinued load EX_WARN
```

Now, the first and second is manageable.

For the third I had to search in the docs. 
If you read [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1008521) you can see that "discontinued loads" include "fatal errors", "CTRL-C", and "space errors".
In this cases I would probably get no records or some records rejected, EX_WARN return code, and the file incomplete loaded in database.

If there are no records rejected is simple: it was a discontinued load. I must exit with error.
But when I have some record rejected I'm not sure that my file is completely loaded in database. (Some rows rejected is acceptable to me.)
Am I right?

If yes, what the solution? 
How do I know if the entire table was loaded into DB?

Comment: Is there a question here? Seems more like a rant.

Comment: I posted this because is a good chance that I'm wrong. Probably I missunderstood something.

Comment: "If SQL*Loader returns any exit code other than zero, you should consult your system log files and SQL*Loader log files for more detailed diagnostic information."

Comment: "consult your system log files" is so fuzzy. I must automate this loads. I have dozen of tables that must be loaded every day in night hours. it is not feasible that somebody "consult system logs.".

Comment: So nobody investigates the rejections and discards anyway? You'll never know if the whole file is processed but all records are rejected because of an error from the supplier. If the incoming data is sanitised so that no rejections are *expected*, that return code becomes much rarer and will always indicate something that really does need a manual check.

Comment: Currently the script greps for count of rejected rows. But for me that seems insufficient.

Comment: If you expect errors and are unable to alter your tables / ctl files to get rid of them then you'll need a secondary process to check the log file and see what has occurred. I use python but that's only personal preference.

Comment: Counting just rejected rows doesn't seem enough, but I assume you're looking at the 'successfully loaded', 'rows not loaded' and maybe 'total logical records' lines and comparing with the number of lines in the source file. A discrepancy would then indicate a discontinued load, wouldn't it?

Comment: yes, this is the last solution. count the records to be loaded = count records loaded + rejected. THis involve one more scan of the source file, but i see no other option... thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the situation where SQL Loader inserted (and committed) some rows out of a data file but failed to reach the end of that file (ie there could have been more records after the failure point which would have otherwise succeeded).

I'd opt for an external table over SQL Loader, using an `INSERT INTO dest_table ... SELECT * FROM external_table`. That would be an atomic operation and there's a (generally small) chance that it will fail if you have insufficient undo for rollback (since you are not using intermediate commits).

I'd also minimise the possibilities of rejections in the external table / SQL Loader layer by treating everything as generic text until it is loaded into the database. Then I'd apply the structure and use DML error logging to handle anything irregular. That way you have clear access to the rejected data and the reason for the rejection in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems i was right. 
I count as good solution the Alex Poole's comment, the solution of Gary(recomended also by Tom kyte), and I found another trick in the ecuation with my coleagues:

To put OPTIONS(ROWS=100000000) - more than input data can have - and load conventionaly. (We will have only one commit or none)
With this, we know that, if is loaded something, is loaded everything.